# Erro a importar o numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, matriz

Eu importei a biblioteca numpy, mas tá aparecendo o seguinte erro quando rodo o código:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: Sempre queria saber se isso é só um problema de instalar pacotes pip no interpretador Python errado ou é o vscode errando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se não instalou o modulo como root e está tentando executar o script como usuário comum ou vice e versa.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).